# k8s - Using Promethues with cAdvisor to monitor microservice/Pod data

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, prometheus, prometheus-operator

I'm running `Prometheus operator` in the new Kubernetes cluster and I try to get container details.
The query dashboard of Prometheus doesn't provide any container data, when I look at the target I see the following

[image]

Maybe it's because of the roles but I'm not sure since I'm new to this topic
I saw also this:
https://github.com/coreos/prometheus-operator/issues/867
and I add the `authentication-token-webhook` which doesn't help, but maybe I didn't do it in the right place...

Any idea what am I missing here?

my operator.yml config look like following

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: prometheus-operator
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: prometheus-operator
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: prometheus-operator
  namespace: default
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: prometheus-operator
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - extensions
  resources:
  - thirdpartyresources
  verbs:
  - "*"
- apiGroups:
  - apiextensions.k8s.io
  resources:
  - customresourcedefinitions
  verbs:
  - "*"
- apiGroups:
  - monitoring.coreos.com
  resources:
  - alertmanagers
  - prometheuses
  - prometheuses/finalizers
  - servicemonitors
  verbs:
  - "*"
- apiGroups:
  - apps
  resources:
  - statefulsets
  verbs: ["*"]
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources:
  - configmaps
  - secrets
  verbs: ["*"]
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources:
  - pods
  verbs: ["list", "delete"]
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources:
  - services
  - endpoints
  verbs: ["get", "create", "update"]
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources:
  - nodes
  verbs: ["list", "watch"]
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources:
  - namespaces
  verbs: ["list"]
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: prometheus-operator
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: prometheus-operator
  name: prometheus-operator
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: prometheus-operator
    spec:
      containers:
      - args:
        - --kubelet-service=kube-system/kubelet
        - --config-reloader-image=quay.io/coreos/configmap-reload:v0.0.1
        - --authentication-token-webhook=true
        - --extra-config=kubelet.authentication-token-webhook=true
        image: quay.io/coreos/prometheus-operator:v0.17.0
        name: prometheus-operator
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
          name: http
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 200m
            memory: 100Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 50Mi
      securityContext:
        runAsNonRoot: true
        runAsUser: 65534
      serviceAccountName: prometheus-operator
```

my rbac looks like following

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: prometheus
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: prometheus
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources:
  - nodes
  - services
  - endpoints
  - pods
  verbs: ["get", "list", "watch"]
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources:
  - configmaps
  verbs: ["get"]
- nonResourceURLs: ["/metrics"]
  verbs: ["get"]
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: prometheus
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: prometheus
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: prometheus
  namespace: default
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: prometheus-k8s
rules:
  - apiGroups:
      - ""
    resources:
      - nodes/metrics
    verbs:
      - get
  - nonResourceURLs:
      - /metrics
    verbs:
      - get
```

If some config file is missing please let me know and I'll add it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the below params to kubelet config on each workder node

```
--authentication-token-webhook=true
--extra-config=kubelet.authorization-mode=Webhook
```

then run the below commands

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart kubelet
```

Comment: Thanks, what do you mean in the worker node ? should I add it to some yaml or something ? and where I should run the commands `systemctl` ?

Comment: Hi, I've created a cluster and apply those files, https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1to6bOuhud4DdVjMj2AoZvScUPAJnsiPF?usp=sharing , can you please have a look?

Comment: any idea what could be missing?

Comment: i work in a close network. cant access google drive. you need to add authentication and extra config params to kubelet config file. With the webhook enabled, prometheus would be able to scrape cadvisor metrics from node.That is what i did in my cluster. it works.

Comment: if your cluster is on RHEL or centos then you need to add above params in the following file ( /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service )